# DD4T Xml Serialization Error

Tags: 2013, dd4t

Can you help me out with the following error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: <page xmlns=''> was not expected.]
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPage.Read17_Page() +382

[InvalidOperationException: There is an error in the XML document.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +1435
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle) +163
   DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.GetIPageObject(String pageStringContent) +540
   DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page) +1387
   DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.GetModelForPage(String PageId) +241
   DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.Page(String pageId) +83
```

Any idea why this is happening? The xmlns is not in the broker database.

Comment: Show your code for GetIPageObject(String pageStringContent)

Comment: This error means that the XML that was generated isn't valid. Did you generate the XML using the DD4T TBB's?

Comment: Yes I used the TBB's from DD4T, as I mentioned above, the xmlns statement isn't in the broker database, so it can't come from the tbb's or can it?

The GetIPageObject is from the DD4T Dll's. It is in the PageFactory.

Comment: I've had similar problems, as Albert says, when a non-DD4T template is used - something is affecting the XML. WHen you say "not in the broker database" do you mean that the content published to the Broker is "<page>" without the xmlns?

Comment: Yep, clean xml in the brokerdatabase without the xmlns attribute anywhere.

Comment: Well, something is affecting the XML that's been generated. Just to be certain: your Page Template contains the TBB 'Generate dynamic page'? And your Component Template contains the TBB 'Generate dynamic component'? No other TBBs on your Page/Component templates? (Except 'Publish binaries for page/component' maybe...)

Comment: I've set the TBB's following the example in the 1.31 branch of DD4T. In there the TBB's are as follows: Generate Dynamic Page, Add inherited metadata to page, Publish binaries for page, Convert XML to Java, Minimize XML. The ContentPorter Zip in that branche has the same setup for the PageTemplate.

Comment: Remove the 'Convert XML to Java' TBB

Comment: That strangely did the trick...

Comment: Nice. This TBB is only used in Java projects afaik. Btw, it's a good idea to start with as less TBB's as possible. If you don't have metadata on your components/pages yet, remove the 'Add inherited metadata to page/component' from your template. It saves you a lot of XML and thus performance...

Comment: So... Java DD4T implementations don't need XML namespaces? :-) Don't tell Mihai.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it turned out from the comment from Albert, I had to remove the "Convert XML to Java" TBB from my Page Templates/Component Templates.

Thanks again!